# How to create a gradient backround in the compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I want to add a gradient background to my render, but **within** the compositor (not with the actual *background* world setting of the scene). I would also like to don't have to use an image (neither external nor internal) to achieve that.

I rendered my image with *transparent* enabled in *film* section of *render* panel. Then I tried to add a *ColorRamp* node with an *Alpha over* node, but now I'm stick on how to give a **Factor** to this color ramp.

My thought is to give it some coordinates corresponding to Y axis of the image, but I can't find a way to.

Is there a node that give some image coordinates ? (like *mapping* node in materials)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add a Texture Node with a blend texture and color ramp. You can adjust the gradient using the Color Ramp in the Textures panel. (See image)

[image: Node Setup]

Comment: Not my question but from what I read, this was not what I was expecting as it uses a texture. A good answer nonetheless.

Comment: Well, it actually does the trick, so I'll accept this one. Considering that a "Blend texture" isn't exactly an image... :P Thanks @rioforce!!

Comment: @Polosson I am glad I could help you. :)

Comment: Makes you wonder why every node editor in Cycles has the gradient node available except the compositor...

Answer (score 17):

You can generate a Gradient by displacing a RGB node with a white value on the Y axis, and using that as a factor to mix two colors (Note the Wrap Value on X axis on the Transform node).

[image]
[image]

To soften the edge between the two colors apply a Blur node.
[image]

Then just mix it with your rendered image.

[image]

All done within the compositor, with total control on the placement and softness,
and no need for additional textures or images.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a node exists. However, you can create a gradient fairly easily if you bring in an external image, convert it to BW, move it around and crop it, then blur it.

For example:

[image]

Node setup:

[image]

Comment: Good answer but I think OP was looking for something inbuilt, not external, the amount of nodes you used to blur, why not just import a gradient image or use the world settings. ;)

Comment: @iKlsR yes, you're right I was looking for something inbuilt, not using an external image (nor internal :P). Thanks for the answer BTW @CharlesL!