# How to create less realistic sky in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

My project has a cartoon-y aesthetic (clay-like), and to complement that I want to add a cartoon sky as well. The goals are to be not as realistic and dull, I would want to be able to choose my own colors for below and above the horizon.

At first I've tried hacking something simple together with shaders, but then I realized I am bad at shaders (I couldn't figure out which color to choose from the an RGB Curve node).

EDIT: Something akin to this

[image: this]

, a very simple gradient and sun. The procedural clouds I will add later (though I don't know how to do that, too), the gradient & sun is really all that I need.

Comment: Wow, this is hard to answer without specific examples... unfortunately, there are many, many kinds of 'toon sky'

Comment: Yes, can you provide some image examples?

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: Read: [Cycles world vertical gradient](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60480/how-do-i-make-the-cycles-world-background-a-vertical-gradient) and [how to create a gradient in the compositor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5486/how-to-create-a-gradient-backround-in-the-compositor)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How do you create a gradient texture as the background for your world?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67393/how-do-you-create-a-gradient-texture-as-the-background-for-your-world/67394#67394)

Comment: The above two do not show how to emulate a sun

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40987/how-to-make-a-sun-in-blender/41307#41307 ... you can also use the big search box at the top of the page to find information on this site...

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32849/how-to-make-clouds